# I want to add a param (eg. locale, or session-id) to every link/submit rails generate, is that possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I try to avoid cookies where ever I can. Therefore I want to put `locale` or `session` as 'everytime params' to every 'link_to_tag' or submit button 'per default'. Is that possible with rails standards. If yes how.

wow, thats a short question

I try to explain further:

if a user does not accept cookies, i ask nicely, but he dosnt accept. Its ok, but I would like to 'store' this info in the links I (rails does) generate, something like:

```
http://mydomain.earth/.../...?id=2&...&cookie=dontask
```

So I just dont ask again if this param is set. And if this param is set, I want rails to put it into every link it generates.

(this is not a security question, so please avoid answers like 'dont put session info into URL')

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bother? It also makes sharing links a bit trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rails (version specific) way:

[default_url_options](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options)

Basicaly

> Overwrite to implement a number of default options that all
>   url_for-based methods will use. The default options should come in the
>   form of a hash, just like the one you would use for url_for directly